# why do arabic and farsi(or any arabic based character) get scrambled in python IDE and Tkinter based apps?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I could not find things on this anywhere
my exact question is why are the written characters SCRAMBLED when the so called 'text cursor' goes in a Arabic character string
like this:

[image]

if you cant see the image its something like this:
*in the python default IDE or IDLE v3.12.1*
the way its displayed:حبیبی| سلام علیک یا
the way it must be displayed:سلام علیک یا حبیبی

and yes the same thing happens on every tkinter multi-line input or tkinter Text widget

I mean this isn't an extreme case but it can be worse than this at times the words become completely unreadable and its been quite hard making go with these in huge text entries (at least for me)if you know why this is happening or know how to solve this problem please help. remember aligning/justifying it wont do as i have already tried those' and no its not a version specific problem either i have tried this on every god forsaken version of python.

Comment: Just a heads up the RTL text seems to be handled correctly is VSCode..

Comment: @JonSG short strings can work in VSCode, but longer texts will have all sorts of defects, wrapping is a nightmare, and the integrated terminal, and depending on the platform the console will not work.

Comment: @hosian, the short answer is that the editing interfaces you are using do not isolated each bidi embedding.